# Matrix of rank one.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ be a matrix of rank $1$. Show that $A$ is similar to a matrix of the form 
$$A'=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \cdots &0& a_1 \\ 
 0&  \cdots&0&  a_2\\ 
\vdots &  &  \vdots&\vdots \\ 
0 &\cdots &0& a_n
\end{pmatrix}$$

Meaning that all columns but the last are zero columns.

Please tell me if my try is correct or is there another simpler way to do it.

**My try:**

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ be the  endomorphism associated to the matrix $A$ relative to the canonical basis $B$ of $\mathbb R^n$. to show that $A$ and $A'$ are similar we show that $A$ and $A'$ are two matrices of the same endomorphism $f$ but relative to different bases. So let's find a basis $B'$ in which the matrix of $f $ is $A'$. The rank nullity theorem gives that $\dim \ker f =n-1$. Let $(b_1',\cdots,b_{n-1}')$ be a basis of $\ker f$. Let $H$ be a complementary subspace of $\ker f$ in $\mathbb R^n$. we have that $\dim H=1$ so let $H=\left<s\right>$.  We have that $f(s)=a_1b_1'+\cdots a_{n-1}b_{n-1}'+a_ns$ for some reals $a_1, \cdots,a_n$. In sum, we have constructed a basis $B'=(b_1',\cdots,b_{n-1}',s)$ of $\mathbb R^n$ in which the matrix of $f$ is $A'$. So $A$ is similar to $A'$.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct. You could make it a bit shorter by saying, after having found a basis for $\ker f$, that this basis can be extended (by one vector) to a basis of the whole space (incomplete basis theorem), and that the first $n-1$ columns of the matrix of $f$ in this basis are evidently zero (the corresponding basis vectors being in the kernel); this is all that matters.